# LinkedIn Company Updates with API Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I have an app that currently allows users to enter in a company name and we use the LinkedIn API to pull all the public posts that this company has made on LinkedIn.

The new API rollout has occurred and while I have a difficult time finding the information I need in the LinkedIn API docs it seems that no one can access company info for a company they are not an administrator of.

I am not trying to access company info or to change their page or anything like that, I just want a list of their public posts. I don't require my users to sign in and even if I did I doubt most of them are administrators of these company pages. Is this totally no-longer possible with the LinkedIn API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new API rules for Company profiles stipulates:

"New requirement for Companies API

All calls to Companies API endpoints will require the authenticated user to be flagged as an administrator of the LinkedIn Company Page that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other LinkedIn members.

Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company."

Link [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).

LinkedIn is making things really tough for everyone. You'll need to apply to be a partner, but even in your case, the admin would have to sign in. Effectively, unless you're akin to a Hootsuite that gets the page admin's rights for the sake of publishing, you're not going to be able to do what you were. Bummer.

Comment: Man, that's a bummer. Can't believe LinkedIn is making that kind of move. Seems silly.